# how to tensorflow processing not use bitmap for android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am developing an app using a camera and tensorflow lite.

I've succeeded in processing images using an image reader, but I want to have no image reader for the performance of my app.

The most effective way I want is to use the surface to create and process the tensorImage.

But I couldn't find this way, and I couldn't implement it.

Can anyone know or help with this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.